# Can a defmacro generate a string with the name of the .el file where it is expanded?

Tags: elisp-macros

I'd like to create a Emacs Lisp macro that is able to generate a string literal that contains the name of the .el file into which the macro is expanded. Is this possible?

**Background**:

I am writing a Elisp macro that generate one or several defun forms.  Some may be inside conditional forms (if or conditions or whatever) and the macro being expanded may also be inside a conditional block form.

Assuming I have the following code inside a file called `my-file.el`:

```lisp
(when some-condition
    (my-macro lisp arg1 arg2))
```

I'd like to be able to write a defmacro form that would be able to determine that it is being expanded inside `my-file.el` and would be able to generate the string literal "my-file".  Something like:

```lisp
(when some-condition
   (defun my-lisp-function (some-arg arg1)
     (some-code-here arg1 whatever))
     (declare-function my-lisp-function "my-file")
   ;;
   (some-other-code etc etc)
   ;;
   (my-lisp-function arg2))
```

In the example above I'm using the file name string literal inside a declare-function form to prevent the byte-compiler from complaining about the generated my-lisp-function not being defined.  And at the same time allow the check-declare package to verify the existence of the function.

I tried to use the variable `byte-compile-current-file` from bytecomp.el by accessing it in the non-generated portion of the macro, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to create a Emacs Lisp macro that is able to generate a string literal that contains the name of the .el file into which the macro is expanded. Is this possible?

If I understood correctly, Emacs 28 adds a function which does this:

```el
(defun macroexp-file-name ()
  "Return the name of the file from which the code comes.
Returns nil when we do not know.
A non-nil result is expected to be reliable when called from a macro in order
to find the file in which the macro's call was found, and it should be
reliable as well when used at the top-level of a file.
Other uses risk returning non-nil value that point to the wrong file."
  ;; `eval-buffer' binds `current-load-list' but not `load-file-name',
  ;; so prefer using it over using `load-file-name'.
  (let ((file (car (last current-load-list))))
    (or (if (stringp file) file)
        (bound-and-true-p byte-compile-current-file))))
```

It follows that some key variables of interest are:

- `current-load-list`
- `load-file-name`
- `byte-compile-current-file`
- `buffer-file-name`

Sample usage:

```el
(defmacro my-foo ()
  "Echo name of file where this macro is expanded or nil."
  `(message "%s" ,(macroexp-file-name)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I need.  I'm not using Emacs 28 yet.  I'll have to try it on that.  I assume that it means that the functionality is not available before Emacs 28.

Comment: Great! But can you please show how that function is used, in the OP's example or otherwise? Its doc string isn't very helpful: *"the file from which the code comes"*. What code? And the doc strings for the two variables used in that code are even worse: the first says only *"Used for internal purposes by `load'."*, and the second doesn't exist (no doc).

Comment: @PRouleau Right, this function does not exist before Emacs 28. But you can inline or copy its definition if you need to.  The idea is to use one of `current-load-list`, `load-file-name`, `byte-compile-current-file`, or `buffer-file-name`, roughly in that order.

Comment: @Basil.  Yeah, you're right.  I'll try that now.

Comment: @Drew I've given a simple example, but the rest of your comment seems like something to take up with the OP and `bug-gnu-emacs`.

Comment: @Basil macroexp-file-name does everything I needed.  I works in macrostep-expand as well as when the code is byte-compiled, as should be expected.  Thanks!